sympy handling of exponents
I'm trying to perform algebraic calculations where both the variable and the exponent are symbols.  But it seems that sympy does not fully understand the meaning of law of exponents:
>>> from sympy import *
>>> u, n = symbols('u n')
>>> u**(2*n) / u**n         # this is good
u**n
>>> u**n / u                # not good
u**n/u
>>> u**n * u                # not good
u*u**n

What can I do to get sympy to turn
u**n / u

into
u**(n-1)

and
u**n * u

into
u**(n+1)?


Has my answer solved your problem? If so, you can accept it.

Tell sympy to simplify the expressions.
>>> from sympy import *
>>> u, n = symbols("u n")
>>> (u**n/u).simplify()
u**(n-1)
>>> simplify(u**n/u)
u**(n-1)
>>> (u**n*u).simplify()
u**(n+1)
>>> simplify(u**n*u)
u**(n+1)


More precisely powsimp() is the function that does this.
